# Facebook Graph Api checkins in geographical area

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Well i want to use facebook's graph api to get checkins from a specific geo-graphical location with python.

In the api documentation area i didn't find the right combinations of api parameters to get it done;

```
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/
```

For example , if i want to get all checkins in coffee-shops in Harvard-square(Boston) what would be the api call ? (without going into specifying every coffee-shop in that location)

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for coffee places as follows:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place.

You can then narrow narrow your search to a specific location and distance by adding the center parameter (with latitude and longitude) and an optional distance parameter:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

This is documented by Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/).